# Unwanted transparency of SwiftUI DisclosureGroup's chevron

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is it a bug or a feature that `DisclosureGroup`'s chevron is semi-transparent?

[image]

The code that results in the view above:

```swift
DisclosureGroup {
  Text("Content")
} label: {
  Text("Label")
    .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
}
  .tint(.red)
  .padding()
```

Using the deprecated `accentColor(_:)` instead of `tint(_:)` gives the same result, as well as default colors:

[image]

```swift
DisclosureGroup {
  Text("Content")
} label: {
  Text("Label")
}
  .padding()
```

How can I get rid of this effect? Any advice is appreciated.

---

**UPD.** Someone marked this question as a duplicate of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77489444/padding-for-the-chevron-of-swiftuis-disclosuregroup-without-affecting-the-group/77492059) about `DisclosureGroup`'s internal paddings. Please don't do that. While these two problems indeed could be solved similarly, or rather with help of the same API, they are still different.

Comment: Pretty sure it is a feature. This is consistent across the controls. e.g. a `Button`'s "pressed" state is also semi-transparent.

Comment: But it's not in the pressed state, it's always like that. When it's pressed, both the label and chevron are semi-transparent. In the normal state, only the chevron is semi-transparent.

Comment: Well, regardless of whether it’s intentional, you can customise it however you want with your custom styles. See the duplicate target. In the end, it doesn’t really matter.

Comment: “Can be solved similarly” is exactly the criteria for determining whether a question is duplicate of another. It’s not about the question, it’s about whether they share the same answer.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. These are two different problems and are searched on the internet differently. Some people may have one problem, but not the other. Additionally, even though two problems can be solved by help of one technique (`DisclosureGroupStyle`,) the final solution is different anyway.