# Padding for the chevron of SwiftUI's DisclosureGroup without affecting the group's content

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is there a way to add an inset on the trailing side of `DisclosureGroup`'s label, i.e., on the chevron side?

When I add `padding()` to `DisclosureGroup`, both its label and contents are indented:

```swift
DisclosureGroup {
  VStack {
    Text("Row 1")
    Divider()
    Text("Row 2")
    Divider()
  }
} label: {
  Text("Label")
}
  .padding()
```

[image]

I want to avoid that and have the contents of the group spread from one edge of the screen to the other, especially `Divider`s.

When I add `padding()` to `DisclosureGroup`'s `label`, the chevron is not indented:

```swift
DisclosureGroup {
  VStack {
    Text("Row 1")
    Divider()
    Text("Row 2")
    Divider()
  }
} label: {
  Text("Label")
    .padding()
}
```

[image]

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisclosureGroup`s are easily customisable with your own `DisclosureGroupStyle`. You can do almost anything you want in a `DisclosureGroupStyle`.

For example, here I made a style with a `Button` as the toggle between the open and close states, with an `Image` of chevrons with `padding()`. I've also tried my best to make the transitions look similar to the default disclosure group style.

```
struct PaddedDisclosureGroup: DisclosureGroupStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    configuration.isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    configuration.label
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: configuration.isExpanded ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.forward")
                        .contentTransition(.symbolEffect)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
            if configuration.isExpanded {
                configuration.content
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .push(from: .bottom), removal: .identity))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DisclosureGroup {
    VStack {
        Text("Row 1")
        Divider()
        Text("Row 2")
        Divider()
    }
} label: {
    Text("Label")
}
.disclosureGroupStyle(PaddedDisclosureGroup())
```

Comment: I appreciate your time and will consider going the direction you pointed out, but it has a major flaw in my eyes: It doesn't tweak the standard UI element, it effectively re-implements the element's UI. If Apple updates how the standard `DisclosureGroup` looks, this implementation will become out-of-sync.

Comment: @lazarevzubov correct. But to be fair, you didn’t want it to look like the “standard” disclosure group anyway. The “standard” disclosure group doesn’t have padding around the chevron.

Comment: That's the only difference. You don't introduce a custom `UIView`, when you only need to change insets of `UIButton`, right? I guess SwiftUI's still not that mature.

Comment: @lazarevzubov Indeed. I think SwiftUI is gradually being updated to match UIKit APIs, but it's not there yet. I remember the days where we had to use the UIKit `UISheetPresentationController` to control presentation detents, but now we have the `.presentationDetents` modifier. That said, I still think it is unlikely for `DisclosureGroup` to allow you to change the padding of the chevron. And as you said, the appearance can change with iOS versions, so in the future it might have more padding *by default*. It can also change to not even using a chevron and you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) is correct that it's impossible to play with the chevron paddings separately, and the best we can do is to revamp `DisclosureGroups`'s UI. The easiest way to achieve that is `DisclosureGroupStyle`, as described in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77492059/7016052).

This answer is just an extension of the proposed solution, which:

1. Improves the expanding/collapsing animation of the disclosed content to match the original UI component's behavior (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70397371/7016052))
2. Improves the chevron animation to make it rotate as in the original UI component
3. Adds an extension to the `DisclosureGroupStyle` that enables more neat usage of the style

The updated implementation of the `PaddedDisclosureGroup`:

```swift
struct PaddedDisclosureGroup: DisclosureGroupStyle {
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    VStack(spacing: .zero) {
      Button {
        withAnimation { configuration.isExpanded.toggle() }
      } label: {
        HStack {
          configuration.label
          Spacer()
          Image(systemName: "chevron.forward")
            .rotationEffect(configuration.isExpanded ? .degrees(90.0) : .zero)
            .animation(.default, value: configuration.isExpanded)
        }
      }
        .padding(.horizontal)
      configuration
        .content
        .frame(height: configuration.isExpanded ? nil : .zero, alignment: .top)
        .clipped()
    }
  }
}
```

The extension:

```swift
extension DisclosureGroupStyle where Self == PaddedDisclosureGroup {
  static var padded: PaddedDisclosureGroup { PaddedDisclosureGroup() }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
DisclosureGroup {
  VStack {
    Text("Row 1")
    Divider()
    Text("Row 2")
    Divider()
  }
} label: {
  Text("Label")
}
  .disclosureGroupStyle(.padded)
```

The result (I added backgrounds and more UI elements around to make the `DisclosureGroup` and its animation more visible):

[image]